# Fetch current user in after_create filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i know that it's a bad idea to fetch the current_user in a model. I also know that there is a way to do it (with Thread). But, i don't want to do it this way(it's certainly a bad idea), so i would like to have an opinion on achieving this a different way.

A user can create a clan, and upon creating it, he has to be the leader. The Clan model is :

```
class Clan < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :assign_leader

    # the person who created the clan is the leader
    def assign_leader
      self.clan_memberships << ClanMembership.new(:user_id => ???, :role => 'leader')
    end
end
```

I know i can just create the membership in the controller. However, i like that filters act as transactions and i would very much prefer a filter for this. But, is there really a correct, non 'hackerish' way of doing that here ?

Comment: What about using virtual attributes? I mean use a virtual attribute in the Clan model named user_id and sets the virtual attribute on creating the Clan. The virtual attribute will be accessible from self.user_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the leader in the controller:

```
@clan.leader = @clan
@clan.save
```

Then your model would look like this:

```
class Clan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leader
  after_create :assign_leader

# the person who created the clan is the leader
def assign_leader
  self.clan_memberships.create(:user => self.leader)
end
```

This means then you could check `clan.leader` for the leader, rather than having to query another association such as `clan.memberships` to find out who that is. It also leads to cleaner code in `assign_leader`.

You will, of course, need to add `leader_id` as a field to your `clans` table.

Comment: nice solution thanx :) Just a notice that it also needs an 'attr_accessor :leader' here.

Comment: @SpyrosP: Don't use `attr_accessor`. leader should be saved as an association on the clan. See my updated answer.

Comment: ahh, i see what you mean, but i don't really want to have a leader_id. I actually save my members through another model(clan_membership), because there are other ranks as well.